# Failed in reading PKCS7 signed file with s/mime format ( big size )

Tags: linux, openssl, pkcs#7, smime

I want to verify signed file with s/mime format and the pkcs7 file size is 500MB.

openssl smime -verify -in test.pk7 -inform DER

Error reading S/MIME message
715956256:error:07069041:memory buffer routines:BUF_MEM_grow_clean:malloc failure:buffer.c:152:
715956256:error:0D06B041:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_D2I_READ_BIO:malloc failure:a_d2i_fp.c:229:

Is it possible with limited memory usage e.g.200MB ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used NSS library which supports chunk-based processing and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, OpenSSL will load the whole file in memory.

If possible switching PKCS#7 detached signatures would reduce significantly the memory requirements. That means having the data and the signature as 2 separate files.

Comment: you mean there's no way to instruct openssl so that it can load file  chunk-wise.

Comment: From the [openssl smime documentation](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/smime.html) there is a `-stream` option, but it doesn't work for verifying non-detached signatures (it works for detached signatures).

Comment: any hopes by tweaking opnessl library code in case of no-detached data ?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with a 1.4GB encrypted file, on 32bit host it failed on mallocs, on 64bit it got through.

Comment: though I am stuck at 5gb now :(

Comment: In linux malloc should not fail but when it will fail in memset ,because you can malloc huge memory chunk even more than system memory size in case of no swap partition.

Comment: I've solved my problem of decrypting the file with the help of openssl foundation. Though there is no easy solution. There is some way to strip all of eencapsulation from the file and operate on chunks of data which avoids loading of the whole file into memory. This is an "unimplemented" feature (AFAIU -stream for -decrypt).

Comment: can u guide me how can i achieve the same ?

Comment: you can talk to openssl users lists, I've paid to one of the authors to write the code but he had explained to me how it works, so if your time is cheaper than mine then maybe you can write it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

As Mathias mentions, you can stream process the data in OpenSSL if the signature is detached.

Now if your signature isn't detached, you should still be able detach it yourself. The PKCS#7 format is well-documented. asn1c can work in chunks so you should be able to work with that.

Of course, the proper solution is to get a detached signature in the first place.